# Ranking up more ranks?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Now with the rank distribution you can derank more ranks(i.e from MGE to GNM). Is it possible to rank up more ranks?

Comment: Your rank has to rebalance but then its progression just like normal.

Comment: I deranked from LE to MG2 :( after 1 game.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, (i.e MGE to GNM), by more deranks you can get more ranks, its pretty much common sense dude :)

Unrelated but helpful link about the CS Ranking system:

http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=260702087

Comment: I mean, it's possible to rank up more ranks in 1 rank up?

Comment: Oh, like instead of going from Silver III to Silver IV, U come to Silver . Jumping two ranks infront.

Comment: Unfortantly, I have to say; No

Comment: Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/GlobalOffensive/comments/2sdjyn/is_it_possible_to_jump_2_ranks/